# class not found exception in react-native-devoice-info

Tags: reactjs, react-native

c++ Exception in "NativeModules": java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/util/zzu

react natie

Comment: Please add more details and describe what you are trying to achieve and what you did?

Comment: If you just installed that package then you need to rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that "react-native-devoice-info" is not correct, it should be "react-native-device-info". There are two simple steps you have to perform as follows:-
1] npm install --save react-native-device-info 
2] react-native link react-native-device-info (for automatic linking)

Afterward you need to rebuild your project and use it in your project as follows:-
var DeviceInfo = require('react-native-device-info');
// or import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info';